# Question of authership. Belonging to two institutions. Are both required to be mentioned?

Tags: authorship

I have a question about my affiliations on my article.

I belong to two institutions, A and B (both are schools).  I have a regular position at A (so I receive a monthly salary from A). I also have a non-regular position at the other shcool, B.

This time, I am contributing to an article as a co-author at school B. Do I need to mention school A as one of my affiliations? (I did not do anything at A. I did not use any resources at A. )

One more question. Do you think school approval (review) at A is usually required ?

Comment: Usually, it is in your best interest to also give school A as your affiliation. That can only help you in your annual performance review. There are no ethical problems here since you actually are affiliated with A.

Comment: @Roland "That can only help you in your annual performance review."  That's a good point, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question will very much depend on the specifics, but I will try to give some rules of thumbs.

> Do I need to mention school A as one of my affiliations?

This depends to a large extent to the relevance of you being affiliated to A to your publication. If the subject of your publication and/or the venue where you want to publish are even partially related to A's activities, then: yes you should present the affiliation.

Let me give an example: suppose you work as accountant at an oil company, and in your spare time you have done some environmental related research. While you might consider you to be unbiased, and the daily activities of your work do not have direct environmental aspects, it is still important for the readership of your article to know that you are professionally affiliated to an oil company. They can then decide for themselves whether they want take that into account when reading your article.

> Do you think school approval (review) at A is usually required ?

This depends very much on the rules that A has in place for their employees, and on your own agreements with A. Read your contract, any other agreements and regulations and ask your boss (or any other relevant person who has the authority to make decisions about this).

Some companies have strict regulations about publishing. You can try to make deviating arrangements, but if you do, make sure they are clear and they are in writing.

Comment: Yeah, in my case, A and B are both in the same field, though they have different foci. I think my view is (somewhat slightly) biased by A. I will mention A. Thank you very much.